# Bring Popup Window To Front VB Website

Tags: vb.net

Working in visual studio on an asp.net webpage in visual basic language. On one page there is a textbox with a lookup button. When the lookup button is pressed, a new smaller popup window pops up, the user clicks on a value which gets posted back to the original page and the popup closes.  I can click the lookup button and the small popup pops up. Now if I do not select a value and instead click back on the website, the popup window obviously loses focus and is moved behind the main webpages window but is still open. If I click the lookup button again, while the first one is still open, the popup window refreshes and reloads itself, but stays behind the main webpage window. How can I bring the popup window back to the front after it is already opened and moved behind the main webpage window? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are already using javascript to get this behaviour, have a look at the z-index.

something like document.getElementById(yourpopupdivId).style.zIndex = "99"; or any other high number will on the element containing your small popup will probably do the trick.